# How to get href value in each a href?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to have for each **a href** the href value and add it to an array.

This is my code so far:

```
$str = "<a href='google.com'>ga naar google</a> <a href='nu.nl'>of ga naar nu.nl</a>";
preg_match_all('/\<a href="{1}([^">]*)\">{1}/', $str, $array);
print_r($array[1]);
```

I tried to do it with preg_match_all and add the values to an array called 'array'. I tried multiple times but didn't get the values that i wanted.

Comment: You say no success, what *did* happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about the difference between double and single quotes.
This is the code that is working for your example. Not only the single quotes were wrong, also some other things like the slashes in there.

```
$str = "<a href='google.com'>ga naar google</a> <a href='nu.nl'>of ga naar nu.nl</a>";
preg_match_all('<a href=[\'\"]([^\"\']*)[\"\']>', $str, $array);
print_r($array[1]);
```

If you want to see the result online: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/67bcd18666c3673ee198615483614970975d980e